# SQL Query collection in Magento

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have this query:

```
        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
->addAttributeToSort('my_attribute', 'DESC');
```

and I want to ORDER the associated products by "my_attribute"

The snippet `->addAttributeToSort('my_attribute', 'DESC');` don't give me the good result because I have numbers stored as text in my atribute.

I have make a test database and I have seen that current query make the good order in my test database:

```
SELECT * FROM length ORDER BY my_attribute + 0
```

My question is: how to add the "+ 0" in my first Magento query to make the good order by :)

**[EDIT]**

Here is my complete modified function :

```
public function getAssociatedProducts($product = null)
{
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = array();

        if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
        }


        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
            ->addAttributeToSort('breite', 'ASC')
            // My Modification 
            ->addAttributeToSort('my_attribute', 'ASC');
            // My Modification 


        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
}
```

**[/EDIT]**

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Are trying to sort using 2 attributes ? I see you are calling addAttributeToSort twice

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this, I would recommend that you check exactly what your collection is doing by:

```
vardump((string)$collection->getSelect());
```

That should return the query being used for retrieving that collection, then you might be able to to use direct SQL instead on your code.

Other option would be to sort the collection using the PHP array sorting functions like:

```
$data = $collection->getItems();  //an array of objects-
usort($data,array('my_attribute','sortByMyAttribute'));
return $data;

function sortByMyAttribute(){
   #
   # Do your desired sort here
}
```

---

Ok after seeing the update code try:

```
   $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
        ->addAttributeToSort('breite', 'ASC')
```

I removed the set positionOrder, let me know how it goes

Comment: I'm exactly searching the syntax to do in : 
"# Do your desired sort here" :) Thanks.

Comment: If your attribute is numeric you could maybe try to use asort instead of usort, also if the answer was useful to you upvotes are more than welcome :P

Comment: Hi Bizboss, Still stuck with the sort? Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Hi, Allan MacGregor, thanks a lot :) I need more help yes !
My attribute is numeric and contains values with comma like :
3 ; 4.5 ;  7.5 ; 11 ; 15
I have not understanded your post :)
I override the file /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php
and I want to sort by my_custom_attribute in the function : getAssociatedProducts

.Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Please add the overrided function to your questions